# How to mark a file at "C:/User/public/Abc/HiddenFile.txt" as Hidden using WiX installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

Using WiX installer, I install an application in C:/ProgramFiles/App folder. In addition to that I want to mark a random file at "C:/User/public/Abc/HiddenFile.txt" as hidden.

My code:

```
<SetDirectory Id="UserPublicAbcFolder" Value="C:\Users\Public\Abc" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="UserPublicAbcFolder" Name="UserPublicAbcFolder" />
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="UserPublicAbcFolder">
  <Component Id="HiddenFile">
    <File Name="HiddenFile.txt" Hidden="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef >

<Feature Id="SomeId" Title="AppName" Level="1">      
  <ComponentRef Id="HiddenFile" />
</Feature>
```

I get compilation error "System cannot find the file 'HiddenFile.txt'".
The "HiddenFile.txt" is a random file that always be present in my "C:\Users\Public\Abc" folder.
I just want to mark it hidden as part of the installation.

Please help me to achieve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a Custom action. As WiX allows us to write Custom Action as C# method, it comes very handy.

Steps I followed:

1. Create a WiX CustomAction project.
2. Write a Action method in C# to update the file permissions.
3. In Product.wxs, under "Fragment" element create a "Binary" element to point to the .CA.dll.
4. Then create a "CustomAction" element under "Fragment" to specify the Action method name to call.
5. Insert the CustomAction into "InstallExecuteSequence" by creating a "Custom" element and specify appropriate value for Before/After attribute.